# Problem with applying differentiation

Tags: derivatives, area, spheres

I am working on the solution of the following problem.

> A cylinder has a flat base on one end, and a hemispherical top on the other. The material used for the hemisphere is twice the cost of the material used for the cylinder per m$^2$. Find the most economic proportions, given that the object is hollow.

I constructed a formula for the cost based on the diagram below:

$ $

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image: Cylinder]

The total cost is proportional to the total materials used; i.e.
$$\mathrm{Cost}\propto \mathrm{Base~Area}~+~\mathrm{Cylinder~Surface~Area}~+~2~\times~\mathrm{Surface~Area~of~Hemisphere}$$
$$\Rightarrow \mathrm{ Cost }=k(\pi r^2+2\pi r(h-r)+2(2\pi r^2))~~~\text{for some }k\in\mathbb R$$
So solving $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\text{Cost})=0~$  should give the optimal proportions. The only issue is that this gives the result $$r=-\frac{h}{3}$$

Which doesn't really make sense to me. How can the radius of the base/hemisphere be a **negative** third of the height? Can anyone help me find the flaw in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume that the volume is fixed so that you get $h$ as a function of $r$ which can be replaced in the expression for the cost. Then solve $\frac {dC}{dr}=0$

Comment: Why must the volume be fixed?

Comment: Because the required proportions will have to be the same whatever the volume. So fix the volume and allow the radius and height to vary accordingly.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. So substituting $\displaystyle h=\frac{V}{\pi r^2}+\frac{r}{3}$ and solving $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\text{Cost})=0$ will give the correct result.

Comment: This question also had a part (a) where I had to find the proportions of radius/height which maximised volume. I constructed the formula $\displaystyle V=\pi r^2(h-r)+\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$ and proceeded to solve $\displaystyle\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}=0$, which gave $r=2h$ as a solution. Is this also incorrect?

Comment: So take the surface area as fixed